# Parsing Apple Pages/ Numbers/ Keynote using Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

Tika-app extracts pages (numbers/keynotes) as zip File and prints only the file names inside it. It doesn't return the exact content inside the document file.

I tried using autodetect parser ,which tried to parse it using IWorkDocument but fails to get content inside of it. Using tika-app-1.22 to extract the contents.

BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

```
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();  
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();  
    try (InputStream stream = AutoDetectParseExample.class.getResourceAsStream("Hello.pages")) {  
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);  
        return handler.toString();  
    }
```

expected result:

> > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....

actual result:

> > Data/92317989_242x291px-small-17.jpeg
> >
> > Data/108151441_276x185px-small-13.jpeg
> >
> > Data/125144832_750x539px-small-11.jpeg
> >
> > Data/200250285_276x185px-small-15.jpeg
> >
> > Index/Document.iwa
> >
> > Index/ViewState.iwa
> >
> > Index/CalculationEngine-4759.iwa
> >
> > Index/AnnotationAuthorStorage-4758.iwa
> >
> > Index/DocumentStylesheet-4762.iwa
> >
> > Index/DocumentMetadata.iwa
> >
> > Index/Metadata.iwa
> >
> > Metadata/Properties.plist
> >
> > Metadata/DocumentIdentifier
> >     D45D90E8-2C22-4115-98BA-1EDBA675DD55
> >
> > Metadata/BuildVersionHistory.plist
> >
> > Template: 09_School_Report (2018-07-03 15:42)
> >       M7.3-5989-2
> >
> > preview.jpg
> >
> > preview-micro.jpg
> >
> > preview-web.jpg

Comment: What version of iWorks produced the file? IIRC apple completely changed the format fairly recently...

Comment: I'm using pages version 8.2, does Tika support the recent version? if not is there any work around to extract contents from the *.iwa inside it?